# I need a RAG formula organising cells less that other cell by 500

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I need help with is a formula to change Red Amber Green when the value of the cell is 500 less than the specified cell. For example

B2 is 3,700 and C2 is 4,000
I need b2 to display as amber because it is within 500 of C2

If B2 is 3,500 or less it needs to be green

And if B2 is 4,000 and greater it needs to be red

Comment: What have you tried? From your question it is not clear whether the problem you face stems from not being able to derive the correct formulae or not applying conditional formatting rules correctly.

Comment: I am just completely stumped as I am familiar with using RAG with dates but just don’t know how to apply it in this instance

Comment: Dates in Excel are just numbers. It should be completely analogous.

Comment: I’m really not that well versed at excel but I am beginning to gain skills because of my job. Is the anyway of explaining how to create the formula?

Comment: To make those comparisons you could take a look at [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2).  The linked page gives plenty of examples on to use it within a formula - this would give you a RAG status: `=IF(B2<=3500,"G",IF(B2>=4000,"R","A"))`.  But what happens if C2 isn't 4,000?  Still check if it's within 500?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to set the background colour of cell B2 based on its relationship with cell C2, you'll need to create three Conditional Formatting rules based on formulas as follows:

- Fill colour = red with the formula `=b2>c2`
- Fill colour = amber with the formula `=c2-b2<=500`
- Fill colour = green with the formula `=c2-b2>500`